# What's the point of a Story Proof?

Tags: probability, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I've been working through the [Stat 110 Lecture Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJd_1H3rZGg&t=1s) and have come across the idea of Story Proofs.

I've read the following from the [author's book](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VmkAAGOYCTORq1wxSQqy255qLJjTNvBI/edit) on the subject:

> A story proof is a proof by interpretation. For counting problems, this often means counting the same thing in two different ways, rather than doing tedious algebra. A story proof often avoids messy calculations and goes further than an algebraic proof toward explaining why the result is true. The word “story” has several meanings, some more mathematical than others, but a story proof (in the sense in which we’re using the term) is a fully valid mathematical proof. *- Introduction To Probability, page 20.*

But what does the proof consist of?

It appears a story proof creates two real-world scenarios that supposedly count the same thing, defines both counting situations in mathematics, and equates them.

Fine, but without checking the mathematics, how can you be certain you are counting the same thing? Surely you end up checking the numerical proof in any case? Doesn't that make the story proof redundant?

Comment: Nobody is proposing that you neglect the mathematics.  As you say, no proof is correct if the math doesn't hold up.  But, say, proving that the appropriate sum of binomial coefficients is $2^n$ by counting all the subsets of $\{1, \cdots, n\}$ in two different ways is intuitive and valuable, without taking anything away from the many purely algebraic proofs of the claim.

Comment: Okay, does the intuition come before the mathematical proof, or after? Or are both common occurrences?

Comment: Both proofs are mathematical.  I'd say either order occurs, but it's probably more common for direct computational arguments to come first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the first time I have encountered the term "story proof".
I have certainly seen many proofs that would be considered "story proofs" according to this definition, but the style of proof has always been called something more specific, such as a *counting argument* or a [*combinatorial proof*](https://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/gmacgill/guide/combargs.pdf).

I doubt that a real-world scenario is required.
I think the author means just what they said about the nature of such a proof:
counting something two different ways is an example of such a proof,
and such proofs generally have more explanation and less algebra (or other manipulation of symbols) than other proofs of the same facts.

Try reading the definition of "story proof" without any preconceived notions of what the "story" part of it is. You might try substituting a random word for "story"; for example, "Basingstoke". So we have,
"A Basingstoke proof is a proof by interpretation," and so forth.
Once you have understood what is meant by such a proof, and perhaps seen a few examples, it might be clearer why an author might consider "story proof" to be a more descriptive name for such proofs than "Basingstoke proof".

Comment: Thank you! That is the conclusion that was slowly dawning on me. That my pre-conceived notion of "story" was upsetting me some how. Are these sorts of proofs only ever used in combinatorics?

Comment: There are "counting" proofs that aren't strictly combinatoric, such as the graph theory example in another answer. I'm sure there are other ways of removing intensive algebra or similar manipulations from a proof, but nothing has come to mind yet. I suppose "not a counting proof" is to broad too jog my memory.

Answer (score 3):

Graph theory provides some simple examples where you can count things in two ways to derive bounds and constraints on the graph. Say we have a graph with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges. Now let's count the vertices by degree so that $n_k$ is the number of vertices of degree $k$. This means that $n=n_0+n_1+\cdots $.

Now we also know that the the number of edges is related to the degree of each vertex. An edge will contribute $2$ to the total degree of the graph and so also have that $2e=n_1+2n_2+3n_3+\cdots$. We can do a similar calculation with the faces so with $f_k$ being a face with $k$ sides we have that $f=f_3+f_4+f_5\cdots$ and $2e=3f_3+4f_4+5f_5+\cdots$. This means we counted $2e$ in two different ways using the faces and the vertices.

While it may seem trivial we can prove some nice results as a consequences. For example if we use Euler's $n-e+f=2$ these equalities can show that $K_5$ and $B_{3,3}$ are non-planar by comparing the average number of degrees and faces. Other more complicated results and inequalities can also be obtained from setting up the counting in this way.

As a final example one of my favorite problems is given a cube that you want to slice like a Rubix cube. If you're allowed to stack the pieces however you like what is the minimal number of cuts required? It's not hard to see that $6$ is an upper bound since we can do parallel cuts on three mutually orthogonal faces. To see that it's minimal consider the faces of the center cube. So here I didn't really have to do a calculation but the rigor is still there when counting.

Comment: Thank you, those are interesting examples. But I'm struggling to see the story aspect. To me it appears you've stated a problem and given two ways to solve it then equated them. Not woven it into a story. What's the takeaway? Does "story proof" mean "intuitive proof"? Or even "intuitive proof by comparison"?

Comment: @Connor it means counting two ways or using a bijection between two sets to claim the identity without having to do algebraic manipulations. Story here is being somewhat used as the antithesis of computational, so more talking and less symbol shunting.