# Are Story Proofs used outside of Probability?

Tags: probability, proof-writing

This is a follow up to this question: [What's the point of a Story Proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804268/whats-the-point-of-a-story-proof)

I have only come across story proofs in the [Stat 110 course by Harvard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJd_1H3rZGg&t=1s), which is about probability. This makes me think they're only used in this field.

Is that accurate? If not, where are they also used?

Comment: Look up combinatorial proof

Comment: Thank you. Are you saying combinatorial proof and story proof are equivalent? And therefore, story proofs $\equiv$ combinatorial proofs, and only occur in counting?

Comment: No, they do not “only occur in counting.” See for example the notes on free probability by Jonathan Novak. The relationship between counting and the central limit theorem is laid out in the first few pages.

Comment: Okay, but you mentioned probability again. Can I assume that, even if it's not counting, they predominantly feature in probability?

Comment: No - a combinatorial argument can be an example of a story proof.   But you could have an example in another topic in mathematics where you say a particular problem (say a complicated integration)  produces the same answer as a different problem (say finding the volume of a simple shape) using an intuitive argument with words.

Comment: @Henry Okay, so a "story proof" is any proof that uses intuition and explanation to drive the point home, rather than mathematical rigour?

Comment: It can be mathematically rigorous while telling a story.

Comment: @Henry Rather than *computational rigour?

Comment: Another example: [Hilbert's Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) is a story proof of a theorem in set theory.

Comment: @awkward Thank you! That's awesome.

Comment: Edward Nelson's proof of the Liouville theorem that [every bounded harmonic function on Euclidean space is constant](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4.pdf) is definitely in the hall of fame. Totally rigorous without any mathematical symbols.